# Why are the output images of marker=3 and marker='3' different in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I extract the SQFT and Price columns from my document and generate a scatter plot with SQFT on the x axis and Price on the y axis.

Then I input that (partial):

```py
plt.scatter(sqft, price, marker = 3, s = 10, alpha = 0.2) # the marker type is **tickdown** 

plt.scatter(sqft, price, marker = '3', s = 10, alpha = 0.2) # the marker type is **tri_left**
```

Why are the outputs two different marker types?

Comment: Why should they *not* be two different marker types? You are passing two different values for the `marker` parameter.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The reason why this is so is because you're passing an integer (i.e. 3) and a string (i.e. '3'). Those are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html), you can find the list of marker types supported by `matplotlib`. As you can see:

- `marker="3"` (class str) is reserved for `tri_left`
- `marker=3` (class int) is reserved for `tickdown`